# Where does Django-oauth-toolkit store the client_id and client_secret?

Tags: django, django-oauth, django-oauth-toolkit

When an application is created and issued a client_id and client_secret using django-oauth-tookit where does it store the client_id and client_secret? How can I manually retrieve/create them?

Comment: client_id and client_secret are saved in `oauth2_provider_application` table in sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

In your auth provider backend, you can access them using something like:

```
from oauth2_provider.models import Application

my_app = Application.objects.get(...)
my_app.client_id
my_app.client_secret
```

Alternatively, you can also navigate to the corresponding page in the Django admin:

[image: Example Django admin page for oauth toolkit application.]